# Cannot Implement Firebase Anonymous Authentication

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a button that signs a user in anonymously to Firebase, receive a callback, and then if the sign in is successful transition to the next ViewController. Extremely new to programming so any help is appreciated:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

 class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBAction func Auth(_ sender: Any) {
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signInAnonymously(completion: <#T##FIRAuthResultCallback?##FIRAuthResultCallback?##(FIRUser?, Error?) -> Void#>)

        //Receive callback showing completion or error, then navigate to next ViewController

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this help. :)

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func Auth(_ sender: Any) {
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signInAnonymously { (user, error) in
           if let error = error {
             print("Sign in failed:", error.localizedDescription)

           } else {
            print ("Signed in with uid:", user!.uid)
           }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a  nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
 }
```

Comment: Looks like it may have worked, however that method was not populating with the user, error parameters when I was searching for it. Why is that?

Comment: Hi, You can listen for authentication state.

`let handle = FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener() { (auth, user) in
  // ...
}`

Answer (score 0):

Import, `FirebaseAuth`

```
Auth.auth().signInAnonymously() { (user, error) in
    if let aUser = user {
            //Do something cool!
    }
}
```